# Android Starting an Intent from Webview (failed credentials) and return to app after confirming AlertDialogue

Tags: android, android-intent

I need some direction on how best to handle a UI issue.

I'm working on an Android app that logins into a web application. I'm using webview to handle majority of the activities in the web applciation. I do have an override on the OnPageFinish method which goes back to my app, based on a url that the web application throws. The two instances this happens is 1.) credentials wrong, 2.) they logged out. Based on that URL match I start a new Intent within the OnPageFinish method. I also have an override on the OnPageStart to find #2 above which is working.

Issue: Because webview sees a specific url when incorrect credentials are used, the OnPageFinish method starts a new intent to go back to my login app. However I want to send up an alert for wrong credentials (#1 above) that the user acknowledges so they understand what the problem is.

When I throw the alert and the New Intent is inside the alert on the OnClick, the webview displays the web application's regular login screen behind the alert which is **not** visually appeasing. The alert does stay (desired behavior) until the person clicks ok on the alert. It will then go back to the app and shut down the webview. If I do the intent first outside the alert's OnCkick, then the alert, then I get the alert and it goes back to login application without the user seeing what the alert was for. It is very quick. Below is an example of what I did so far. I move the method setNewIntent to where I want it.

```
if (urlapp3.equals(url)) {

    error = true;
    setNewIntent(context);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle("Incorrect Credentials").setMessage("Please re-enter your credentials correctly. They are case sensitive.").setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            dialog.cancel();                                    
        }
    }).show();
}
```

The Intent Method

```
public void setNewIntent(Context context){

    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(context,  MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What about just hiding the webview in the OnPageFinished method?

Comment: Tim - Thanks for the tip and I didn't think of that one. Still learning all the methods and other functions. I tried that but the behavior of keeping that dialogue box up until the user confirms it, is not working. I would like the dialogue box to stay up and webview to go down. It almost appears that because the webview's onPageFinish is used, that the alert is tied to that. So when the webview goes away so does the alert.

Comment: Never-mind - Tim - you are good. I just had to restructure a few things. It worked. Tim is right. Sorry it took me a few tries to get it right. Thanks dude.